# How to make a crystal ball with particles inside in cycles

Tags: texturing, particles

i'm new on 3D modeling and Blender, I'm self-teaching the 3D design and I can't find how to make a crystal ball with particles inside that reflect lights incoming in the ball.

I would like to create something like that:

[image: Effect i want, but coming from center]

Any advise to make it?

Comment: Start here: [https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/nodes/index.html](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/nodes/index.html). Specifically with the [Principled](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/nodes/types/shaders/principled.html) shader.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MeObbrfCSUY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured some of it

Here what i got so far

[image]